# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I want to create a new project creation page, the goal is that the user can validate his form, I have an error in the code below

This is the message error :

```
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dash/create/
Django Version:     2.1.4
Exception Type:     UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    

local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected for visibility.

```
@login_required
def createproject(request):
    form = None # added line
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateProject(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('dashboard:dashboard-createproject')
        else:
            form = forms.CreateProject
    return render(request, 'dashboard/createproject.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all path define the form instance (eg. user use GET to view the page), to fix this just initialize form to None or something before the if statement

Comment: Still have an error :     ```  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateProject(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('dashboard:dashboard-createproject')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateProject
    return render(request, 'dashboard/createproject.html', {'form': form}) ```